# Use Python package "requests" within Palantir-Foundry transforms

Tags: python-requests, palantir-foundry

Making a basic https-get request from a pipeline transform results in "connectionError".
How should one consume an API using the "requests" library to extend some data within a pipeline?

```
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform_pandas
import requests


@transform_pandas(
    Output("..."),
    df=Input("..."),
)
def compute(df):

    # Random example
    response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')

    print(response.content)

    return df
```

results in

[image]

[image]

Is this a configuration issue?

Comment: I would suggest to read the docs on this: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/
Under normal circumstances Foundry is network egress constrained.

Comment: @nicornk - the link says, transformation doesn't support having inputs

Comment: I wasn't sure if the API calls in the question really require Inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Following @nicornk's comment and [the docs on external transforms](https://palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms), using external APIs from within Palantir is restricted by default and requires several administrative steps. The steps to call external APIs from within pipeline transforms are:

1. Check the settings of your code repository
   [image: settings]
2. Add the library "transforms-external-systems" to your code repositories libraries.
   Adding the library, adds a new icon [image: icon] in the control panel on the left.
   [image: add library]
3. Click on the new icon and import an egress policy, if any available. Otherwise try to create a "network egress policy", which usually involves an approval process.
   [image: external systems settings]
4. After having managed to "import"/install an egress policy into your code repository, import methods from the package "transforms.external.systems" and decorate your transformation, following the [docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/#write-external-transforms-logic).

Comment: Note that with sufficient administrative privileges, specific base URLs can be written to a whitelist. API calls to base URLs which are on this whitelist, can be done by requests-calls without requiring any additional steps like importing the package "tranforms-external-systems" package....